# Passing database name to SQL query without SQL injection

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core, exception, sql-injection

I need to pass a database name to my SQL query without SQL injection.

I first get a list of all the databases and check if my passed database name is in the list. If yes, I escape my database name and pass it to my SQL query. Is this the correct approach to prevent SQL injection as I can't parameterize the database name. Also, how should I handle the exception? Is ArgumentException okay?

```cs
public async Task<int> GetTableId(string database)
{
    int res;

    using (IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(_settings.SqlServerConnString))
    {
        try
        {
            string sqlDatabases = $"SELECT [name] FROM [sys].[databases]";
            List<string> resDatabases = db.Query<string>(sqlDatabases).ToList();
            if (!resultDbList.Contains(database))
                throw new ArgumentException(nameof(database));

            var builder = new SqlCommandBuilder();
            string sanitizedDatabase = builder.QuoteIdentifier(database);

            string sqlId = $"SELECT DISTINCT [Id] FROM {sanitizedDatabase}.[dbo].[Table]";
            res = db.Query<int>(sqlId).FirstOrDefault();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger.LogError(e, "Error querying table id from database", new { database });
            throw;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Parameters are used to pass data, just like parameters in a function. A database name isn't data. It's closer to the name of an assembly

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I understand that a database name isn't data and that I can't use SqlParameter for the database name like I would use for a column value like `Id = @Id`. However, the database name is dynamic in this case and I just want to confirm if this is the best approach to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: If you understand it's not name, you should understand there's no way to pass that name without constructing a string command, even if that's a `USE someDB;`. You can specify the database name in the connection string, with the `Initial Catalog=myDB` parameter. Switching to another database requires an explicit command though

Answer (score 1):

The database cannot be parameterized, so that leaves limited options:

- concatenation; as per your example, although it may be advisable to use `[your db name here].whatever` to handle spaces etc (although you'd also want to check for `]`!)
- via the `USE dbname;` statement (not really any better than the first option, and less portable - plus it still needs to be a literal, not a parameter)
- specifying the database in the connection string, or via the user's default database

Constantly concatenating literal database names into every query is going to make for a *lot* of string allocation churn, so if you *can* do this at the connection level (via the connection string), that would probably be a lot more efficient.